# Building hello world at the command line using Cmake and Visual Studio Express 2010

Tags: cmake

I'm new to CMake. I am trying to build a very simple program (hello world) using Visual Studio 2010 Express. In the Visual Studio 2010 Command Prompt I ran the command:

```
cmake -g "NMake Makefiles" .
```

This appeared to work.

```
C:\Users\david\dev\cmake\hello_world>cmake -g "NMake Makefiles" .
-- Building for: Visual Studio 10
-- Check for working C compiler using: Visual Studio 10
-- Check for working C compiler using: Visual Studio 10 -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler using: Visual Studio 10
-- Check for working CXX compiler using: Visual Studio 10 -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/david/dev/cmake/hello_world
```

Next, I tried to run nmake, which produced the following error:

C:\Users\david\dev\cmake\hello_world>nmake

```
Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 10.00.30319.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

NMAKE : fatal error U1064: MAKEFILE not found and no target specified
Stop.
```

I cannot see a Makefile inside the project directory, so I guess that's why it is not working, or perhaps CMake uses a non standard name for Makefile's? I'm unsure. I've pasted the contents of the project directory below.

```
C:\Users\david\dev\cmake\hello_world>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 4000-10E9

 Directory of C:\Users\david\dev\cmake\hello_world

08/05/2012  01:38 PM    <DIR>          .
08/05/2012  01:38 PM    <DIR>          ..
08/05/2012  01:38 PM            28,584 ALL_BUILD.vcxproj
08/05/2012  01:38 PM               735 ALL_BUILD.vcxproj.filters
08/05/2012  01:38 PM            12,871 CMakeCache.txt
08/05/2012  01:38 PM    <DIR>          CMakeFiles
08/05/2012  01:34 PM               151 CMakeLists.txt
08/05/2012  01:38 PM             1,514 cmake_install.cmake
08/05/2012  01:38 PM             3,150 hello_world.sln
08/05/2012  01:38 PM            36,618 hello_world.vcxproj
08/05/2012  01:38 PM               671 hello_world.vcxproj.filters
08/05/2012  01:37 PM             2,213 hello_world.vpj
08/05/2012  01:37 PM               206 hello_world.vpw
08/05/2012  01:37 PM               134 hello_world.vpwhist
08/05/2012  01:37 PM           106,496 hello_world.vtg
08/05/2012  07:14 AM               118 main.cpp
08/05/2012  01:38 PM            23,914 ZERO_CHECK.vcxproj
08/05/2012  01:38 PM               807 ZERO_CHECK.vcxproj.filters
              15 File(s)        218,182 bytes
               3 Dir(s)  134,161,678,336 bytes free
```

The source for my program is:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::cout << *argv << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

My CMakeLists.txt is:

```
# CMakeLists.txt
# $ cmake -g "NMake Makefiles" .

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(hello_world)
add_executable(hello_world main.cpp)
```

Thanks,

Comment: I managed to generate a makefile by using the cmake-gui which worked with nmake. Anybody know why the -g "NMake Makefiles" option did not work from the command line?

Comment: The correct flag for specifying the generator is "-G" (upper case). The lower case "-g" will be ignored by cmake and thus cmake will use the default generator.

Comment: As an alternative: You could generate 'standard' "Visual Studio 10" solution files and call 'msbuild ALL_BUILD.vcxproj' instead of nmake.